# Adding guests to calendar event by script without invites being sent

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

what I would like to do is add guests to certain google calendar events via a script I created without them being notified via an invitation. I tried the addGuest() function but whenever someone is added he or she is getting an invitation email.

Is this possible?

Thank you very much in advance.

Best, Phil

EDIT:

Thanks for your answer. Yes I'm sure there ere invites being sent. Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
for (i = 0; i < events.length; ++i)
{
 if (events[i].getLocation().match("XYZ") || events[i].getTitle().match("ABC")) {events[i].setLocation(addabc) && events[i].addGuest(mailxyz)}  
}
```

EDIT 2: I verified again, that invites are indeed being sent out. Here is my entire script, butI have no idea which part might cause this:

```
function ModifyAppointments() {  

 var idabc = "idabc..."


  // ABC
  var contactabc = ContactsApp.getContactById(idabc);
  var addressabc = contactabc.getAddresses();
     var addabc = addressabc[0].getAddress();
  var mailsabc = contactabc.getEmails();
     var mailabc = mailsabc[0].getAddress();


  var today = new Date();
  var start = new Date();
  var end = new Date(start.getTime() +(500 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7));

  var events = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getEvents(start, end);



   for (i = 0; i < events.length; ++i)
   {

   if (events[i].getLocation().match("abc") || events[i].getLocation().match("abc") || events[i].getTitle().match("abc") || events[i].getTitle().match("abc")) {events[i].setLocation(addabc) && events[i].addGuest(mailabc)}  

   }

}
```

EDIT 3: Here is a screenshot of one of the invites that was being sent. Unfortunately it is in German:

[image: screenshot of invite]

If you wonder why there is such a lage time between the sending of the invite and the date an time of the appointment, I used to have a larger time interval in my script. Now i shortened it to a week in advance.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure they're being sent an invite? There's an open issue for this at https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=574 because this function *does not* send an invite, and it's requested that it does. 

I've also just tested this again myself, and this function did **not** send me an invite, so either this is not the method being used to send your invites (Is there another function in your code sending the messages?). If you post the code that is causing the issue it might be easier for us to identify exactly what's happening.

Comment: @user1582830 have you checked the calendar settings of the account you use to test this ? if you set the notifications there then I think any event (created by a script or using the calendar Ui) will create a notification, either by mail or with a popup.

Comment: @Sergeinsas that's an interesting question, but these would be 'reminders' not 'invitations' if I understand what you mean. @ user1582830 perhaps you can provide a screenshot of the notification they receive which would confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a look at this, and I'm absolutely positive that this code is not what is sending the invite. As I said, there's an open issue for this at https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=574 because this function *does not* send an invite, and I've also just tested this again myself, so we can rule that out.

Here's a test function that you can copy and paste and place someone else's (Invites are never sent to the creator of the event) email address into a new script and confirm for yourself that .addGuest() is not the culprit:

```
function myFunction() {
   var email = 'ANOTHER-PERSONS-EMAIL-HERE';
   var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createAllDayEvent('Apollo 11 Landing',new Date('November 20, 2014'));
   event.addGuest(email);
}
```

The remaining assumption is that some other portion of your script is sending out the invite (Once again, it is **not** possible for the Calendar service in the script to send an invite).

Comment: I just modified my original question. I still have no idea what might have caused this. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Attach a screenshot of the invite that's received, that will help.

Comment: I just attached a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from how you wrote your code. You have to iterate over an array of events. I have fixed it for you.

```
function myFunction() {
    var today = new Date();
    var email =  'ANOTHER-PERSONS-EMAIL-HERE';
    var events = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getEventsForDay(today);

    for (i = 0; i < events.length; ++i)
    {
        events[i].addGuest(email);
    }
}
```

// Let me know if you have any questions - amir@serialmetrics.com, Amir Behbehani, // Chief Scientist, Serial Metrics